# Running queries for specific versions of Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql

I want to run a CQL query for specific versions of Cassandra, so if the version is less then or equal to 3.11.10 I want to query to return results. I am checking the 'release_version' column in the 'system.local' table. For example:

select * from system.local where release_version <= '3.11.10';

This works for some versions of Cassandra however as the '<=' is doing a string comparison test I will get false positives on other versions like if the version of Cassandra is '3.11.8' no results will be returned. How can I check the version of Cassandra ?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that the query is changed to just select the version with no where clause - the logic of interpreting the version number and making the decision on the potential execution of a following query is handled within the application code.